# how to render address in textarea with only street, city and zipcode except geo property which is another nested object?

Tags: reactjs

> right now my address field is showing [object Object]. So, how to show only street, city and zipcode inside textarea ? The API that i am using is jsonplaceholder/users/1. The nested object contains
> "name":"Leanne",
> "address":{"street":"kulas", "city":"Johannesburgh", "zipcode":"123456", "geo":{"lat":"-23", "lng":"24:}}

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        users: {
            name: '',
            address: '',
        },
    }
    this.getOneUser = this.getOneUser.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
}
async getOneUser(){
    try{
        const {id} = this.props.match.params;
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${id}`);
        if(!res.ok) throw new Error('could not fetch');
        const data = await res.json();
        const {name, address} = data;
        this.setState({users: {name, address}});
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.getOneUser();
}

onChangeHandler(e){
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    this.setState({...this.state, users: {...this.state.users, [name]: value}});
}

render() {
    return <div className="mb-3">
        <textarea name='address' value={`${this.state.users.address}`} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} className="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="floatingTextarea"> 
        </textarea>
    </div>
}
```

[screenshot of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypq4h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your API, you receive the following object:

```json
{
  "name": "Leanne",
  "address": {
    "street": "kulas",
    "city": "Johannesburgh",
    "zipcode": "123456",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-23",
      "lng": "24"
    }
  }
}
```

So when you run the code

```js
const {name, address} = data;
this.setState({users: {name, address}});
```

You're setting `this.state.users.address` to object given by the APIs `address` property, which is as follows:

```json
{
  "street": "kulas",
  "city": "Johannesburgh",
  "zipcode": "123456",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-23",
    "lng": "24"
  }
}
```

So to extract the street, city, and zip code, you can access this object and put each of these properties individually into your text area like so:

```
render(){
  let addr =  this.state.users.address;
    return (<div className="mb-3">
        <textarea name='address' value={`${addr.street}, ${addr.city}, ${addr.zipcode}`} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} className="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="floatingTextarea"> 
        </textarea>
    </div>)
}
```